# Rails Has Many Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, many-to-many, has-many-through

So this whole many-to-many thing has me really confused. I get how to set it up but I can't seem to find anywhere that really explains the best way to use it in your controller.

**What I have:**

Products, Orders, Orders_Products

The Products and Orders table has the standard stuff (Id, name, timestamps, etc)

The Orders_Products table has the two id columns (order_id, product_id) and a quantity column.

**What I need to do:**

Now when I save my "cart" how do you save a new order and each product with its quantity?

This is my first app in rails so the more explanation the better.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

To start, you should only have two tables, Orders and Products.
Here is a great guide I was given in one of my questions - guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Have a read of that to familiarize yourself with associations in rails, but pretty much what you are trying to achieve is the following -

In your order model have the relation

```
  has_many :products
```

And in your products model have the relation

```
  belongs_to :order
```

That way you can link your products to your orders. Then you can make calls like

```
  order.products
```

which will give you all the products for a particular order.

In your migrations you will need to give your products an order_id to make that association between orders and products.

In terms of saving the products to an order, you will do that in your products controller either by associating the order_id in to some form in your view and sending the order id through the params hash, and just write

```
   product = Product.create(params[:product])
```

or you can do it in your controller and say

```
   product.order_id = @order.id
```

@order can be found from the order id from your url in your products controller, so you just make a method saying

```
   def find_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
   end
```

and at the top of the controller before any actions you can say

```
   before_filter :find_order, :only => :youractiontosaveproducts
```

and what that will do is find the order you are saving the product to before that action is called.

To write all the code in an answer is a bit of overkill, a read of that guide and some practice will get you on the right track :)